# Check if a range is null or empty

Tags: c#, epplus

I am checking for a particular column is empty or not in excel using epplus.
but the worksheet.cell[] method only takes the range which is not null and I want to check that particular range is null or not.

```
foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells["" + firstRowCell.Address + ":" + Regex.Replace(firstRowCell.Address, "[0-9]", "") + "" + worksheet.Dimension.Rows])
{
    while (cell.Value == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (Regex.Replace(cell.Address, "[A-Z]", "") == worksheet.Dimension.End.Row.ToString())
    {
        worksheet.DeleteColumn(1);
    }
    break;
}
```

I am not able to check the range is null as it does not enter the loop.

Comment: Also, changing the enumerable (deleting a column) while looping over it is a bad idea.

Comment: You might want to output `["" + firstRowCell.Address + ":" + Regex.Replace(firstRowCell.Address, "[0-9]", "") + "" + worksheet.Dimension.Rows]` to a console to see why your loop isn't entered